# A small doubt regarding a previously asked limit of convolution

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convolution

Previously, I asked this question to the forum.

> [Pointwise limit of convolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417064/pointwise-limit-of-convolution)

Now, a question in this regard is coming to my mind. Suppose, we don't have the integral; i.e. we have the expression:

$(\omega_{\epsilon}(t-t_{1}) - \omega_{\epsilon}(t-t_{2}))$ & multiplied by $f_{\epsilon}$ (i.e. $f * \omega_{\epsilon})$ . & we ask the same question.

i.e.: What will be the limit: $\lim _{\epsilon \to 0} (\omega_{\epsilon}(t-t_{1}) - \omega_{\epsilon}(t-t_{2})) f_{\epsilon} $ ??

I am asking this question just based on curiosity!! Because I know $f_{\epsilon} \to f$ a.e. as $\epsilon \to 0$ ; But what about the additional $\omega_{\epsilon}(t-t_{1}) - \omega_{\epsilon}(t-t_{2})$ ??

Comment: We have (if $\omega$ is compactly supported) that $\omega_\epsilon (s)\to 0$ for all $s\neq 0$. For $s=0$, we have $\omega_\epsilon (s)\to \infty$ if $\omega(0)>0$. This should give you the answer for almost all cases.

Comment: @PhoemueX , So.. since: $t \neq t_{1}$ & $t \neq t_{2}$; we will have: $[\omega_{\epsilon}(t-t_{1}) - \omega_{\epsilon}(t-t_{2})] \to 0$. right??

Comment: Yes, if you assume $t \neq t_1$ and $t \neq t_2$, this is true. You even have (this is more strong) $\omega_\varepsilon (t - t_1) = 0$ for all sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$ (depending on $|t - t_1|$ and on $\omega$). Thus, no matter with what you multiply $\omega_\varepsilon (t - t_1)$ it will still converge to zero.